# Swift delegate isn't calling

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I am currently in the process of writing a program but i kept running into an issue with the delegate. So I stepped back and wrote a smaller program just to test delegate functionality and try to understand the concept and I am still unable to get it to work, I've been all over this page and tried every suggestion that I've seen and nothing seems to be working. This simple program has a navigation button that brings up a new view controller. On this controller I have a navigation button called Save. When I press the Save button its supposed to call the delegate function and print something to the console, but its not printing. Here is the code I am working with.

```
import UIKit

class ListViewContrroller: UITableViewController, 
AddItemViewControllerDelegate {



let CellIdentifier = "Cell Identifier"
var items = [Item]()

// Mark: Initialization
required init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: decoder)

    // Load Items

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    title = "Items"
    print(items)

    // Register Class
    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.classForCoder(), forCellReuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier)

    // Create Add Button
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(addItem))

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


// MARK: - Table view data source
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return items.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // Dequeue reusable Cell
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath)
    // Fetch Item
    let item = items[indexPath.row]
    // Configure Table View Cell
    cell.textLabel?.text = item.itemName

    return cell
}

//Mark Helper Methods

// Mark: Add Item button pushed
@objc func addItem(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    //print("New Item button was pressed")
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "AddItemViewController", sender: self)
}

// Mark: -
// Mark: Delegate Methods
func testDelegates() {
    print("hi")

}

// MARK: - Navigation

func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "AddItemViewController" {
        if let navigationController = segue.destination as? UINavigationController,
            let addItemViewController = navigationController.viewControllers.first as? AddItemViewController {
            addItemViewController.delegate = (self as AddItemViewControllerDelegate)
        }
    }
}
```

}

and my second View Controller

```
import UIKit

protocol AddItemViewControllerDelegate {
    func testDelegates()
}
class AddItemViewController: UIViewController {


var delegate: AddItemViewControllerDelegate?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}



// MARK: - Navigation



// Mark -
// Mark: Actions
@IBAction func cancel(sender:UIBarButtonItem) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func save(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

        // Notify Delegate
        print("Pre-Delegate message")
        delegate?.testDelegates()
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

At the end of everything my console looks like this

```
[]
Pre-Delegate message
```

Which shows that my array is empty and the save button is being recognized. Any help you can provide will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you sure the line `addItemViewController.delegate = (self as AddItemViewControllerDelegate)` is actually running?  Put a breakpoint there, or a diagnostic print statement to make sure.

Comment: And if it *is* running, your first view controller might be getting deinitialized before the delegate func is called, causing `AddItemViewController.delegate` to be nil when it is needed (since it is a weak reference).

Comment: Do you embed the second vc inside a navigation ??]

Comment: No, the prepareForSegue function does not appear to be called at all

Comment: @eric-mccracken : open your storyboard select the segue, go to property inspector, find the field called identifier and add the string as "AddItemViewController" run the code again :) that should do the job

Comment: @SandeepBhandari: The Segue has always had AddItemViewController as its Identifier. Do i need a second segue back from the navigation controller?

Comment: @eric-mccracken : Show us your segue, add a screen shot by opening the property inspector displaying the identifier

Comment: In your `ListViewContrroller`, the "prepare for segue" func signature should be `override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` ... if it's not currently being called, it looks like you just have it mis-written.

Comment: @DonMag This was what fixed it. Thank you Very Much!

Answer (score 0):

The Prepare for Segue function was incorrect. I had

```
func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
```

when I needed

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
```